# Can't Get Custom Module/Block To Work

Tags: magento-1.9, module, blocks

I am very close probably just an XML mistake somewhere. Please assist.

I'm making a custom module.

The directory structure:

In `/var/www/html/magento/app/code/mine/MINE`

```
-etc
--config.xml
-Catalog
--Block
---List.php
```

My `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Mine>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mine>
    </modules>
<global>
        <blocks>
            <mine>
                <class>Mine_Block</class>
            </mine>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

My `List.php`

```
    class Mine_Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
    {
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
             $category_id = 3;
             $category2B = $this->getNameInLayout;
             if($category2B =="itemsShoes"){
                $category_id = 3; //important
                    }                  
 collection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        return collection;
    }
   public function zetLoadedProductCollection()
    {
    return $this->_getProductCollection();
    }
    }
```

My module registry in `/var/www/html/magento/app/etc/modules`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--Mine-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mine_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>mine</codePool>
        </Mine_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

It is titled `Mine.xml`

And finally, my template (`slider/shoes.phtml`):

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->zetLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: 
foreach ($_productCollection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName(); 
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And my local.xml`:

```
<block type="page/html" name="shoeFinder2" module="mine" template="slider/shoefinder2.phtml">
<block type="mine/list" name="itemsShoes" module="mine" template="slider/shoes.phtml"></block>
<block type="mine/list" name="itemsClothes" module="mine" template="slider/clothes.phtml"></block>
<block type="mine/list" name="itemsTennis" module="mine" template="slider/tennis.phtml"></block>
</block>
```

So what am I doing wrong? I don't even get a "There are no products matching the selection." from the `getProductCollection()` attempt, so I know there is a configuration error rather than a collection error.

I just get an empty `div`.

Comment: Are you really sure you run this function and not any other getLoadedProductCollection()?

Comment: @Phil Pretty sure, that file is the only php file in my module as set in the block.

Comment: Well, I comment out the `getLoadedProductCollection()` and I get the same result? How can I debug the module code to see an error like, function not found?

Comment: Please provide your config.xml file and layout update xml file if any along with the file path. Without this, we can't direct you in the right way.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy Please see updated question...

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are fetching category in your custom page then your declartion should be as below

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="itemsShoes" category_id="4" module="Mine" template="slider/shoes.phtml"></block>
```

here 4 is your category Id

and yes you have to change your block type as yours this `catalog/product_list` will point `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`

Comment: How do I overrite that class so I can still point to that type? Also I want the category id to be assigned based on the nane attribute.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of mistakes.

First of all I will start with naming the module.

Change this `/var/www/html/magento/app/code/mine/MINE` to `/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community/Mine/MyMine`. Remember, we are placing your extension in `app/code/community` folder. You can usually place in community or local.

Now, your folder/file structure:

```
Mine/MyMine/etc/config.xml
Mine/MyMine/Block/List.php
```

Your `config.xml` should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Mine_MyMine>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mine_MyMine>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mine>
                <class>Mine_MyMine_Block</class>
            </mine>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Your `List.php` (You shouldn't use `Mage` in naming your module, `Mage` should be reserved for core.) And it should reside this way `app/code/community/Mine/MyMine/Block/Product/List.php`

```
class Mine_MyMine_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
             $category_id = 3;
             $category2B = $this->getNameInLayout;
             if($category2B =="itemsShoes"){
                $category_id = 3; //important
                    }                  
 collection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        return collection;
    }
   public function zetLoadedProductCollection()
   {
    return $this->_getProductCollection();
   }
}
```

Most importantly your module activation in `/var/www/html/magento/app/etc/modules`

true
            community

Finally, your `local.xml`

```
<block type="page/html" name="shoeFinder2" module="mine" template="slider/shoefinder2.phtml">
<block type="mine/product_list" name="itemsShoes" module="mine" template="slider/shoes.phtml"></block>
<block type="mine/product_list" name="itemsClothes" module="mine" template="slider/clothes.phtml"></block>
<block type="mine/product_list" name="itemsTennis" module="mine" template="slider/tennis.phtml"></block>
```

**You haven't fully included your `local.xml` here, so there should be more logic in it to get it work, since you are not overwriting `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` block.**

This should help.